# How to access the data in javascript from the ctype pointer of type uint8_t

Tags: javascript, ctypes

I am having some data in ctype uint8_t type pointer which I want to read into the var array in javascript.

I have done simple for loop to copy the data,

`for(var j = 0x00; j < 5; j ++) {
  var dataReceived[j] = ptr[j];
}`

but when tried to display data in alert window, it is showing "undefined".

Can anybody help me to copy data from ctype uint8_t pointer to var array?

Is there any mechanism to copy data?

Vishal N

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [contents] property of a pointer ctypes object can be used to access the object it points to.

try this:

```
for(var j = 0x00; j < 5; j ++) { 
    var dataReceived[j] = ptr[j].contents; 
}
```